# distance between first and second place, or, first and third place - Prolog

Tags: prolog, distance

The title may be confusing so I'll try explain it better here.

I've created some queries to store data of the distance between two places.
For example:

```
miles_between(60, aberdeen, dundee).
```

This is meant to say that the distance between aberdeen and dundee is 60 miles.

I've created another query that the distance between X and Y is the distance between Y and X.

I want to be able to create this query: The distance between a first and second place is the miles from the first to the second or the miles from the first to a third place plus the distance between the third and second place.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this. I've currently created I believe to be the beginning of the code for this query:

```
equal_distance(X,Y,Z) :- miles_between(X,Y,Z); miles_between(X,Z,Y).
```

If anyone could explain to me what needs to be done possibly step by step and explain what I'm doing wrong, that would be great! thanks :)

Apologies if this question is hard to understand.

Comment: As a point of terminology, `miles_between(60, aberdeen, dundee).` is a fact, not a query. :) If you have two definitions for distance between two cities that could either apply, you can define them with two different predicate clauses. One would be, `equal_distance(Miles, Origin, Destination) :- miles_between(Miles, Origin, Destination).` and the other would be, `equal_distance(Miles, Origin, Destination) :- miles_between(Miles1, Origin, X), miles_between(Miles2, X, Destination), Miles is Miles1 + Miles2.` But I don't understand why you call it `equal_distance`. What's "equal" here?

Comment: Ah sorry, I've not studied prolog for a few years and have forgotten nearly everything I knew! Yeah I misread the question at first and didn't update my code. I've currently called it total_distance. I've actually managed to figure out the problem and I'm going to add an answer soon explaining it. Thanks for your feedback! :)